# Encryption and Decryption string with openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have no problem encryption function, and do it right But I have trouble Decryption function and does not give the right answer.
I realized that I did in the debug output EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, out_buf + oLen1, &oLen2) function returns zero and I feel that the problem of this function.

please help
This is my program,in C language :

```
char* encrypt(char *buf) {

char* out_buf;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
unsigned char ckey[] = "0123456789";
unsigned char ivec[] = "0123456789";
int oLen1 = 0;int oLen2 = 0;
int fsize = sizeof (buf);
out_buf = malloc(strlen(buf));

EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), ckey, ivec);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, out_buf, &oLen1, buf, fsize);
EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, out_buf + oLen1, &oLen2);
return out_buf;
}

char* decrypt(char *buf) {
char* out_buf;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
unsigned char ckey[] = "0123456789";
unsigned char ivec[] = "0123456789";
int oLen1 = 0;
int oLen2 = 0;
int fsize = sizeof (buf);
out_buf = malloc(strlen(buf));

EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), ckey, ivec);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, out_buf, &oLen1, buf, fsize);
EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, out_buf + oLen1, &oLen2);
return out_buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char* outenc=NULL;
 char* outdec=NULL;
 outenc=encrypt("Hello");
 outdec=decrypt(outenc);
 printf("Encryption is : %s\n",outenc);
 printf("Decryption is : %s\n",outdec);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: please help me.

Comment: please help me.